# openmp parallel for object methods

Tags: c++, object, thread-safety, openmp

i was trying this parallel for which calls methods of a subclass. Unexpectedly the final result is always random. I guess the problem is in calling a class method, but mine only return values without modifying any attribute. Do you have any suggestion about thread-safety or how to fix this? Thank you

```
int temp=0;
int val=0;
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(4) private(temp) reduction(+:val)
for(int i=0;i<MM1.MD.size();i++){
    for(int j=0;j<MM2.MD.size();j++){   
        for(int k=0;k<MM3.MD.size();k++){
            for(int l=0;l<MM4.MD.size();l++){
                temp=          MM1.MD.Get_C()*
                               MM2.MD.Get_C()*
                               MM3.MD.Get_C()*
                               MM4.MD.Get_C()*
                               calc_val(MM1.P[i],MM2.P[j],MM3.P[k],MM4.P[l]);
                val+=temp;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: not an answer , but why using openMP when c++11 provides you with std::thread?

Comment: Try defining the sizes before the loop and using the constant values (e.g. `int nMM1 = MM1.MD.size()`).

Comment: Solved. In the calc_val() function i was modifying the attribute of an object, so i declared that class as static and i inserted the string                                 #pragma omp threadprivate(class_name). After that it worked